# Scaling X Axis as Quarters From Input Date Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am very new to d3.js. I have been working on an example where in my input data is in below format.

```
dataset = [
{"date": "1/10/2014",  "value": 1000},
{"date": "1/15/2014",  "value": 2000},
{"date": "2/5/2014",   "value": 3000},
{"date": "3/20/2014",  "value": 4000},
{"date": "3/25/2014",  "value": 5000},
{"date": "4/15/2014",  "value": 6000},
{"date": "5/5/2014",   "value": 7000},
{"date": "6/12/2014",  "value": 8000},
{"date": "6/10/2014",  "value": 9000},
{"date": "7/15/2014",  "value": 10000},
{"date": "8/15/2014",  "value": 11000},
{"date": "9/15/2014",  "value": 12000},
{"date": "10/15/2014", "value": 13000},
{"date": "11/15/2014", "value": 14000},
{"date": "12/15/2014", "value": 15000}
```

];

I have to draw two sets of bar charts on my web page one with dates on X-Axis & value on Y-Axis which i am able to do. The another set has to have quarters of a year on X-Axis derived from the input date & the values appropriately distributed within that quarter. I have been trying hard to build that but i am not able to provide a proper scaling for my X-Axis.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe pop some code where you are with it on a fiddle or block or something. Have you tried getting your data into quarters ?

Comment: Hi my jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/manish8187/anggjfg8/

Comment: To get the data grouped into quarters, look into [`d3.nest`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest). You'll want to supply a key function that takes `d.date` and returns a string such as `"q1"` or `"q1_2014"`. After applying the nesting, you'll end up with a mapping between keys (one for each quarter) to arrays of date+value objects. Not totally sure what you mean by "the values appropriately distributed within that quarter", but if you need to reduce the array to a single value for each quarter, you'd use the `rollup` function of `d3.nest`.

Comment: Thanks for the info meetamit. I was able to resolve my issue using D3 nesting & time scale.